# [GCP][Node] serve [Expressjs] app via HTTPS from GCP Compute Instance

Tags: node.js, express, google-compute-engine

I have an express app running on a Google Cloud Platform Compute instance. I would like to serve it via HTTPS. The react app on client side gives me the following:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ahv-client.now.sh/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://<GCP COmpute IP>:<PORT>/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NBgB8QR'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: Is your node server created by `https`?

Comment: @HalilÇakar yes.`let server  = https.createServer(config , app);`

Comment: And the config is also contains your ssl key's ?

Comment: Yes i created Them via openssl. both key.pem and cert.pem are there in the root folder of my project

Comment: Aight how do you create your `socket` instance on your frontend? [Last Question] :)

Comment: socket instance ? i dont understand. you mean the connection to socket.io that i have from react app to this server ?

Comment: Yes that one, how do you create it? `io()` like this directly or are you giving any option

Comment: This is how my react app connects with socket io  `socket.io static socket: SocketIOClient.Socket = socketIOClient(API.network, {
        reconnection: true,
        transports: ['polling', 'websocket'],
        upgrade: false,
        multiplex: true,
    });`

Comment: Aight what does this `API.network` give's you back. Probably it tries to connect via `http` to your `https` server

Comment: Yes API.network holds a string value that is the address to this machine/ server  (IP:Port). although the address starts with http. my connection is declared not secure by chrome , firefox  and React.js

Comment: Like i said, just try to console it and probably you will see that it starts with `http://`, if it's just replace it with `https://`

Comment: i have replaced it with https. i have installed ssl certificate on my vm. created the node server with https.createServer.... but still its not working properly

Comment: Oh i was almost sure that it's not connection because of this.. Aight can you add this to your server side io creating, `require('socket.io').listen(server, { secure: true, origins: '*:*'  })` I'm guessing you are creating your `io` instance like this

Comment: the socket.io error is one of the issues. my express api is also running on this machine and that can't be accessed either. let me make that change and get back to you

Comment: i've added origins property. in      ` "socket.io": "^2.3.0"` there is no 'secure' property. its still the same

Comment: I have kinda exact same setup like this and it's working, maybe your ssl is not working properly? After all these changes i don't think there should be a problem really